# Ajax append new data but links do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have something similar to this:

```
$('.new-post').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/somehting'
    data: {my data},
    ...etc,
    success: function(data) {
      $.get('template.html', function(h) {
        var el = $(h);
        el.find('items').text('texts...');
        el.appendTo('.myElement');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I'm posting a new post using `ajax` and I wish that after it has been saved to the server it is appended to the existing posts list.

It works fine but if I click on links that I append using the html template nothing seems to work...

Probably I used a wrong strategy to do that, so here I need a bit of your help.

I used `$.get` within the `success` method in order to get an html template where to insert new post data to append. I know that `$.get` is async but for some reason it doesn't work until I don't refresh the page...

EDIT (HTML)

```
<li>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
  <ul class='actions'>
    <li><a href='link to the post'></a>
    <li><a href='#' data-modal='comment-modal'>Comment</a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: "nothing seems to work" is an awfully vague problem statement. What do you expect the links to do, and what happens instead? (For instance: Do you expect an event handler related to the link to be triggered? If so, [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) are for you.)

Comment: I expect the link go to the page... it's a link but it doesn't fire. `a href="http://www.google.com"` it doesn't work. Even if I wish to open a modal it doesn't work.

Comment: what kind of links are there => post the html that is rendered in your question pls?

Comment: HTML has been added to the post. Both the actions link doesn't work until I don't refresh the page

Comment: ok the issue when data are loaded to your site using ajax, the there is no jquery bindings. what you need to to do is register the actions for the content.

Comment: Have you tried to use load instead get $( .element" ).load( "template.html", function() {
 $('.actions a')[0].text('...');//i don't know what you need
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add the rebinding in the `success` handler if you want to execute it *after* the Ajax call:

```
success: function(data) {
    elem.replaceWith(data);
    $('.actions').bind('click', /* some function needs to go here*/);
}
```

check following links

> [1]: http://api.jquery.com/live/
>    [2]: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
>    [3]: http://api.jquery.com/on/
>    [4]: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you append, but if your append something which contains `<a href="your url"> Text</a>` then link should work. Insted if you want tu simulate your link, let's say you have somethink like this `<span class="myclass">Click here</span>` you should add an jQuery event:

```
el.find("span.myclass").click(function(){
    //do something 
})
```

I hove I understand what you want to do.